# How to send a custom token to a exchange stellar wallet, Plz help?

Tags: token, trustline, wallets, exchanges, ico

I can create tokens on Stellar but I'm facing a serious issue and I'm really frustrated plz help me.

So, I successfully created a Token on Stellar named "TBTC" and it's in the distribution wallet right now, but here is the thing, you need Both public and private key in order to create "change trust" between two wallets for a payment, and the token I've created is for a ICO which I've to send to a guy in his Exchange wallet (it accepts tokens) so I asked for his stellar wallet address and he gave his exchange's stellar wallet address, but now how can i send the the token to his address, it can't send token without a trustline, and it needs a secret key which obviously none of the exchange provide, so plzzz plzz help me, I'm in serious stress right now!

I just want to send those tokens to his exchange address, plz help!

Answer (score 1):

The person you are trying to send a token to has to set a trustline himself (with a change trust operation) to your issuing account. If his exchange wallet does not allow for it then he will have to use a different wallet that allows him to set trustlines.